# How to pass arguments between QThread and QGui?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qthread

I work on QtGui app with socket programming in back ground I want to take the IP address and port from line edit in gui and deliver it to QThread
the thread is work but I can't pass the arguments I try using constructor but it's stop all project.

I want to pass the arguments to constructor or custom function in the class from Gui before start the QThread works.

Also I need to make plot to data received from socket.
So any way for solve that
I try with passing objects pointers to class but get a lot of bugs

Here the thread code and the ui code

```cpp
//client code
#include "clientclass.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

clientClass::clientClass(char *serverIp, unsigned int serverPort, char *idname ="SCR")
{
    this->ip=serverIp;
    this->port=serverPort;
    this->id=idname;


    std::cout<<ip<<port<<id<<std::endl;

};

int clientClass::connection()
{

    SOCKET socketDescriptor;
    int numRead;

    char id[20]="SCR";

    unsigned int maxEpisodes;
    unsigned int maxSteps;
    char trackName[1000];
    BaseDriver::tstage stage;

    tDriver drive;
    strcpy(drive.trackName,trackName);
    drive.stage = stage;


    tSockAddrIn serv_addr;
    struct timeval timeVal;
    fd_set readSet;
    char buf[UDP_MSGLEN];

    // Create a socket (UDP on IPv4 protocol)
    socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (INVALID(socketDescriptor))
    {
        response = "Error: cannot create socket";
        return (1);
    }

    // Set some fields in the serverAddress structure.

    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons((this->port));
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(this->ip);
    //std::cout<<serv_addr.sin_port<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr<<std::endl;

    bool shutdownClient=false;
    unsigned long curEpisode=0;
    do
    {

        do
        {
            // Initialize the angles of rangefinders
            float angles[19];
            drive.init(angles);
            string initString = SimpleParser::stringify(string("init"),angles,19);
            response =QString ("Sending id to server: %1").arg(id);
            initString.insert(0,id);
            response =QString("Sending init string to the server");
            if (sendto(socketDescriptor, initString.c_str(), initString.length(), 0,
                       (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                       sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            {

                response ="Error: cannot send data ";
                CLOSE(socketDescriptor);
                return (1);
            }

            // wait until answer comes back, for up to UDP_CLIENT_TIMEUOT micro sec
            FD_ZERO(&readSet);
            FD_SET(socketDescriptor, &readSet);
            timeVal.tv_sec = 0;
            timeVal.tv_usec = UDP_CLIENT_TIMEUOT;

            if (select(socketDescriptor+1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &timeVal))
            {
                // Read data sent by the solorace server
                memset(buf, 0x0, UDP_MSGLEN);  // Zero out the buffer.
                numRead = recv(socketDescriptor, buf, UDP_MSGLEN, 0);
                if (numRead < 0)
                {
                    response ="Error: didn't get response from server";
                }
        else
        {
                    response = "Received";

                    if (strcmp(buf,"***identified***")==0)
                            break;
                }
          }

        }  while(1);

    unsigned long currentStep=0;

        while(1)
        {
            // wait until answer comes back, for up to UDP_CLIENT_TIMEUOT micro sec
            FD_ZERO(&readSet);
            FD_SET(socketDescriptor, &readSet);
            timeVal.tv_sec = 0;
            timeVal.tv_usec = UDP_CLIENT_TIMEUOT;



            cout<<"in connection"<<endl;



            if (select(socketDescriptor+1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &timeVal))
            {
                // Read data sent by the solorace server
                memset(buf, 0x0, UDP_MSGLEN);  // Zero out the buffer.
                numRead = recv(socketDescriptor, buf, UDP_MSGLEN, 0);

                if (numRead < 0)
                {
                    response = "Error : didn't get response from server";
                    CLOSE(socketDescriptor);
                    return (1);
                }

                if (strcmp(buf,"***shutdown***")==0)
                {
                    drive.onShutdown();
                    shutdownClient = true;
                    response="Client Shutdown";
                    break;
                }

                if (strcmp(buf,"***restart***")==0)
                {
                    drive.onRestart();
                    response ="Client Restart";
                    break;
                }
                /**************************************************
                 * Compute The Action to send to the solorace sever
                 **************************************************/

        if ( (++currentStep) != maxSteps)
        {
                    string action = drive.drive(string(buf));
                    memset(buf, 0x0, UDP_MSGLEN);
                    sprintf(buf,"%s",action.c_str());

        }
        else
            sprintf (buf, "(meta 1)");

                if (sendto(socketDescriptor, buf, strlen(buf)+1, 0,
                           (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                           sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                {
                    response = "Error : cannot send data ";
                    CLOSE(socketDescriptor);
                    return (1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response ="Server did not respond in 1 second ";
            }
        }
    } while(shutdownClient==false && ( (++curEpisode) != maxEpisodes) );

    if (shutdownClient==false)
    drive.onShutdown();
    CLOSE(socketDescriptor);
    return 0;
}

>
```

```cpp
// ui code 
<
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>
#include <time.h>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    thread =new QThread();
    QString response;

    mine = new clientClass("127",3001,"SCR");

    mine->moveToThread(thread);


    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()),mine, SLOT(connection()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete thread;
    delete mine;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    thread->start();

    if(thread->isRunning()) std::cout<< "is running"<<endl;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class `Worker` Subclassing `QObject` and use signals/slots to communicate between your worker and the UI.

In my opinion, it would be easier to create a new worker each time that you want to run the process than reuse the same worker. So, you have to delete the worker before creating a new one. You can use `QObject::deleteLater` slot for that.

You need a signal in the `Worker` class triggered when you have to send results to UI and a slot in your `MainWindow` to process the result.

You also need a flag to stop the worker and break the infinite loop.

An example of a worker:

```
class MyWorker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWorker(QString const& aAddress, unsigned int aPort, QObject* parent=nullptr): QObject(parent),
        address(aAddress), port(aPort)
    {}
    virtual ~MyWorker()
    {
        qDebug() << "Deleted" << address << port;
    }
public slots:
    void run()
    {
        running = true;
        int count = 0;
        while(running)
        {
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
            for (int i = 0; i != 100000; ++i) { // Long time processing
            for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i) {}
            }
            ++count;
            resultAvailable(QString("Loop count %1").arg(count));
        }
        finished(); // Inform that the worker has finished its task
    }

    void stop() // Call it to stop the thread
    {
        qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
        running = false;
    }
signals:
    void resultAvailable(QString const&); // Will send message to the UI
    void finished();
private:
    QString address;
    unsigned int port;
    bool running;
};
```

A UI that call the worker and display the result received from it.

```
class MyWindow: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWindow(QWidget* parent=nullptr): QWidget(parent),
    address(new QLineEdit),
    port(new QLineEdit),
    ok(new QPushButton("Run")),
    label(new QLabel())
    {

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(address);
        layout->addWidget(port);
        layout->addWidget(ok);
        layout->addWidget(label);
        connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyWindow::process);
    }
public slots:
    void process()
    {
        // Create a new worker and its thread
        QThread* workerThread = new QThread(this);
        MyWorker* worker = new MyWorker(address->text(), port->text().toUInt());
        worker->moveToThread(workerThread); // Put the worker in a dedicated thread

        connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, worker, &MyWorker::stop); // If user clicks on the ok btn again, delete the previous worker
        connect(worker, &MyWorker::resultAvailable, this, &MyWindow::processResult); // Process the data sent by the worker in the UI
        connect(worker, &MyWorker::finished, workerThread, &QThread::quit); // Stop the thread when the worker has finished
        connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, workerThread, &MyWorker::deleteLater); // Delete the thread when finished
        connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &MyWorker::deleteLater); // Delete the thread when finished
        connect(workerThread, &QThread::started, worker, &MyWorker::run); // Starts the worker when the thread is launched
        workerThread->start(); // The worker will be called
    }

    void processResult(QString const& result)
    {
        label->setText("The result: " + result);
    }
private:
    QLineEdit* address;
    QLineEdit* port;
    QPushButton* ok;
    QLabel* label;
};
```

Comment: `running` can be modified in one thread and accessed by another at the same time. This is undefined behavior. Also, calling `deleteLater` in the class itself can be dangerous. You have to ensure that the object was initialized dynamically.

Comment: `running` is modified in a slot which is executed in the receiver's thread. Thanks for the `deleteLater`: I forgot to move this one before my copy/paste...

Comment: No, `worker` lives in the main thread, so `Worker::stop` will be called in the main thread when the button is pressed. In the docs: [*It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run(). This means that all of QThread's queued slots and invoked methods will execute in the old thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke slots in the new thread must use the worker-object approach; new slots should not be implemented directly into a subclassed QThread.*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: Oh nice. You found a bug in our system. I'll update my answer by using a `QMutexLocker` to fix this problem and an alternative with a real worker. Thanks